# Openssl certificate request failed

Tags: openssl

I want to create certificate request with openssl. I am required to have use 'E' for the email field name in the subject. So I have tried the following command:

```
openssl req -new -key privkey.pem -subj "/E=example@example.org" -out request.pem
```

In response I get:

```
Subject Attribute E has no known NID, skipped
```

What does exactly as it sayis. If I add more arguments to subject they are added, but email is skipped.

I have tried google and this same error message comes up several times, but I failed to find solution.

I have tried openssl 0.9.8o and 1.0.1c.

Answer (score 15):

The short name you're looking for is "emailAddress", rather than "E". This works:

```
openssl req -new -key privkey.pem -subj "/emailAddress=example@example.org" -out request.pem
```

Comment: If someone does see a wrong formatting of sub, do not worry. It is just a way it is shown. http://marc.info/?l=openssl-dev&m=106233499931935&w=2